# Can't see arrow in datapicker in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, sonata, symfony-2.8

I don't have a lot of experience with symfony, but im trying to show arrow in datepicker in symfony. Any ideas, why i cant see them? Im using symfony 2.8.

Image:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZHg.png)

fragment of my build form function:

```
 ->add('dateOfBirth', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                'required' => false,
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
            ))
```

Comment: This is not a symfony problem, it's an issue of your Datepicker library (or maybe of your CSS)

Comment: So you mean i should maybe add sth in  my jquery-ui.css? Could you help me? What it should be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQueryUI Datepicker prev and next icons not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017579/jqueryui-datepicker-prev-and-next-icons-not-showing)

Comment: I have pictures in my resources, but I think the problem was not set any picture in  jquery-ui.css
in my case a helpful (i can see any icons finally!) was a 

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870927/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-icons)

Thanks for help